# Databases in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to create a social media type app using Codename One. In order to do this, I was wondering which database service I should use within my application: just the Storage class, SQLite, or MySQL? I expect to be storing significant amounts of data further down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage and SQLite are device databases where in Storage you would normally want to store small amounts of data mainly for caching and offline purposes and SQLite for larger sets of data where you might need more sophisticated queries on the data.
MySQL is a server side database, if you're building a social app you can use mysql on your server to store your data and connect with http/https to the server and query the data to display on the device.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi, the link you sent me talks about Storage and SQLite but I didn't see any mention of MySQL.... is it possible to use MySQL with Codename One? And is there any link on the Codename One website that shows how to integrate MySQL within your app? Thanks.

Comment: Chen's answer is correct. Notice he explained that MySQL is a server side technology and doesn't run on the device. I just provided the link to go with his answer. If you want to use sqlite that is explained there. If you want to use networking to connect to a server that is running MySQL that is also explained there.

Comment: Just to add to this there is this new post covering connectivity to mysql in the backend: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database.html